# Any suggestions about why a 2017 iMac (Catalina) is now consistently hanging on shutdown?

Tags: imac, shutdown

I've had occasional issues with my 2017 iMac hanging on shutdown, just sitting there with the background image and the dock up, but all apps closed and neither the menu bar nor any of the desktop icons showing. And it stays that way until I reach in and hold the power button until it does a hard-shutdown.

And now that I'm mostly migrated to my new M2 Mini, it's done it consistently all week. In fact, this time, I shut it down several hours early, just to see if it will eventually complete the power-down without my having to resort to the power button.

This seems rather different from the symptoms described in other "hanging on shutdown" threads.

Comment: Boot it in verbose mode and see the messages at shutdown

Comment: @lhf: Just hold Command ⌘ + V at boot? And given that FileVault is active; how long do I hold it? I'm planning on just letting it sit for the rest of the day (it's been like this over half an hour now) and trying verbose mode tomorrow morning.

Comment: It eventually did shut down. After over an hour.

Comment: @lhf: Actually, it didn't. The screen blanked, but eighteen hours later, it was still powered up, and still stuck showing background image and dock, but no icons or menu bar.

Comment: @lhf: Booting in verbose mode shows a lot of messages. Shutting down after having done so looks, so far, exactly like shutting down after a normal boot does: desktop background and dock, no icons, no menu bar, and no messages.

Comment: @lhf No change after a full hour -- verbose boot had no apparent effect on the shutdown.

Comment: Oh well, it was worth trying

Comment: And now it's shutting down normally. I'm going to dig around in the logs.

Comment: And today, it's back to hanging.